# Can't replicate condition with ternary operator

Tags: php

I'm trying to replicate this condition:

```
$sth = $this->getResult();
if($sth !== true){
   return $sth;
}
```

with ternary operator I tried with;

```
($sth !== true) ?  return $sth : ($sth == true) ? null;
```

But I got:

> Expected colon

Comment: And why are you trying to replace it? Doesn't the original look more readable to you?

Comment: I just want learn how to do this with ternary, but yes the first is more readable

Comment: What happens if `$sth` is true? Return false?

Comment: @Objective_d if is true just continue the code, infact `$sth` contains an error description to be returned..

Comment: What you want is not possible, a ternary operator always needs a `true` and `false`. Example: `return (statement) ? true : false;`

Comment: @Daan uhm so what is the existence sense of ternary operator at this point? very sad.

Comment: "so what is the existence sense of ternary operator at this point? very sad." - that's like asking what the + operator is good for if you can't do `$x = 3 +;`

Comment: You can't `return` within the ternary operator the same way you can't say `$value = return 3;` . It basically acts as a value.

Comment: @VolkerK heh, you're right. Well I guess I need back to normal if statement

Comment: @Sandokan return from what?

Comment: @Objective_d from another function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're ultimately trying to achieve is not possible with a ternary operator.

What you try to do is ONLY return in 1 situation, and continue the code in the other. The only way you could do this using a ternary operator is like this:

```
$result = ($sth !== true) ? true : false;
if ($result) return;
```

But that kinda defeats the purpose of the ternary operator.

---

In fact, your code has a couple of problems:

- Ternary operator always needs 3 parts (*)
- There is no need to check a condition twice, as that's the entire point of the operator
- The operator returns a value, so you can't put a `return` inside the truthy or falsy part.

**A ternary operator needs 3 parts**

```
(condition) ? truthy result : falsy result
```

*Note: Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise. - source: [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)*

**No need to check things twice:**

Again, let's take our operator:

```
($sth !== true)
                ? "I return if '$sth' is not true"
                : "I return if '$sth' is true";
```

There is no need to have a 2nd check. You have both situations covered already. :)

**No return values inside the truthy or falsy part**

Finally: it is an operator that returns a value. You can't put a `return` in the truthy or falsy part, you need to put it in front of it:

```
return ($sth !== true)
                ? "I return if '$sth' is not true"
                : "I return if '$sth' is true";
```

Comment: I don't think it does need 3 parts, you can miss out the 'truthy result'

Comment: @Objective_d Indeed: [Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: @Jordumus I mean, your code working if I need to return a result from a function, but if I need to continue the code the ternary condition is usefulness in this case. I don't if you have understood what I mean. Maybe take a look at the topic comments.

Comment: @Sandokan Thank you for the reply, I added another part to my answer. Hope it's all clear now.

Comment: @Jordumus yes is clean, but I think that I'll back to use normal if statement.. For this situation, is better, I guess. Thanks for the great anwer.

Answer (score 0):

You have two '?'s in your code, and only one ':'. I believe that's the matter. You must have the same amount of question marks as you have colons.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it to return from a function I would do it like so:

```
function testFunc()
{
    //arbitrary setting of $sth only to explain the point
    $sth = false;

    //condition ? true : false
    $outcome = ($sth === true) ? true : false;

    return $outcome;
}

// false
var_dump(testFunc());
```

Remember, (condition) ? value if true : value if false;

You can also miss out the [value if true] parameter, like so:

```
$outcome = ($sth === true) ?: false;
```

That expression would assign the value of `$sth` to `$outcome` if `$sth` was true.

Comment: Isn't my example, for this I don't understand how to fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your replacement code indeed misses a colon at the very end. It is syntactically incorrect.
If `$sth !== true` you return `$sth`. If not, you start a new ternary statement (that is not complete) which I cannot properly fathom. It now does not look at all like the original statement.

Comment: Well your're using an operator I've never seen before.

Comment: `!===` should be `!==` or not?

Answer (score 0):

The ternary operator is nice and useful, but it's not a block of commands. It is a decision on a value. Rule of thumb, if you can assign something as value to a variable you can use it within the ternary operator :

```
$var = 3;         // valid
($condition?3:0); // valid

 $var = return 3; //Invalid
 ($condition?return 3:null) //Invalid
```

You need to:

```
return ($sth !== true?$sth:null);
```